# How to toggle form visibility dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have page where user can dynamically create new forms. For every new form button is created. Form is hidden by default. I need to toggle form visibility on that button click. Right now i am using javascript code below and its working

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#button1").click(function(){
            $("#1").css({"display":"block"});
            $("#2").css({"display":"none"});
            $("#3").css({"display":"none"});

        });
        $("#button2").click(function(){
            $("#2").css({"display":"block"});
            $("#1").css({"display":"none"});
            $("#3").css({"display":"none"});
        });
       ...
```

Now when user create form i manually modify javascript but problem is that i have too many forms right now and ill have even more.
I need solution to bind button for form and toggle its visibility. Any advice is appreciate.
EDIT
Code i am actually using:

```
while ($row = $result9->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            echo "<input class='btn btn-default' type='button' id='".$row['o_ime']."'  name='button' value='".$row['o_ime']."'>";
        }
echo "<form class='form-inline' role='form' name='$i' id='$i' style='display:none' action='naruci.php' method='POST' onsubmit='return validateForm()'>";
form elements
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: is the button inside the form?

Comment: @Desperado no its not thats why i have problem ill edit post and add code i am actually using

Comment: that will help, post it please

Comment: @Desperado i added code i am actually using if u have any question feel free to ask me.. thxs btw

Comment: is the value of this one `$row['o_ime']` unique for each button? If it's unique then you can set this value as the Id of your form appended by some string (e.g. `form_button1`). So the trick is this, when I click any button, I will just capture the id of the focus button and append `form_` in front of it and use this string to look for the right form to show. Quite clever!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you cannot have the same ID in your DOM.

So instead of IDs use classes. And use [jquery's class selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

So to capture the event, just use the class selector.

And also use hide and show jquery APIs to [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/)/[hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) elements.

```
 $(".new-btn").click(function(){
       $("form").hide(); // close all forms
       $("this").closest("form").show(); // show parent form
    });
```

And the next thing I notice, for dynamic elements it cannot be captured by normal click event. Use jquery on API.

```
$(".new-btn").on('click', function(){
    $("form").hide(); // close all forms
    $("this").closest("form_").show(); // show parent form
                                       // This is the reason it is not working because I forgot the underscore
});
```

Update: 
It should look like this:

```
while ($row = $result9->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    echo "<input class='btn btn-default' type='button' id='".$row['o_ime']."'  name='button' value='".$row['o_ime']."'>";

    // We changed the form ID in this section   
    echo "<form class='form-inline' role='form' name='$i' id='form_".$row['o_ime']."' style='display:none' action='naruci.php' method='POST' onsubmit='return validateForm()'>";
    form elements
    echo "</form>";
}
```

In my query I will create an event to capture my button clicks:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(){ // Listen all click events of buttons with class `btn`
    var id = $(this).attr('id');  // Get ID of focus button
    var formName = 'form' + id;   // Append form string in the id to match form's ID

    $('form').hide();             // Hide all forms
    $('#' + formName).show();     // Show exact form
});
```

Comment: Its nice idea, but its not  working, anyway thxs ill try to find  if i missed anything and use ur idea @Desperado

Comment: @StefanMichelangeloMihajlovic I cannot guarantee that this will work because I don't have the complete tools :) It is nice also for you to experiment in your own, just fill the gaps that im missing

Comment: @StefanMichelangeloMihajlovic of course I created a working fiddle for you, because I cannot control the urge to do it so, Please see link https://jsfiddle.net/aj9yggb2/

Comment: WORKING LIKE A CHARM!! your idea is perfect, i missed one or two things in my own code.. Lots of thanks saved my day

Comment: @StefanMichelangeloMihajlovic told yah, you can make things work if you experiment

Answer (score 1):

you'll find the best way of what you want to do by following the example here in this link

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("p").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add unique class for all of your forms. Refer this code

```
<form class="test" id="1"></form>

<form class="test" id="2"></form>

<form class="test" id="3"></form>

$(document).on("click",".test",function(event){
     $(".test").css({"display":"none"});
     $(this).css({"display":"block"});
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

Just make your own class for display block.

```
.db{
display:block;
}
```

Then on your jquery just toggle class.

```
 $("button").click(function(){
$("#1").toggleClass('db');
})
```

Comment: Ok, but do i need to modify script every time new form and button is created?
$("newbutton").click(function(){
$("#newform").toggleClass('db');
})

Comment: @StefanMichelangeloMihajlovic use classes so you don't need to create new events repeatedly, look at my answer

Answer (score -1):

```
\\对于动态生成的元素需要使用`on`来监听事件的触发
```

Try the following

```
$(function(){
        //动态构造form元素
        //Dynamic construction of form elements
        $('#cnf').on('click',function(){
            $('#container').append('<div>' +
                                        '<button>toggle</button>' +
                                        '<form><input value="value"></form>' +
                                    '</div>')
        });


        //通过冒泡监听按钮事件
        //The bubble monitor button event
        $('#container').on('click','button',function(){
            $(this).next().toggle();
        })

    })
```

祝顺利！